# gitlab-ci.yml python -c 'multiple line cmd' failed

Tags: python, yaml, gitlab-ci

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` I need to have multiple line python -c 'stuff on multiple lines'

with this:

```
image: python:latest

before_script:
  - |
    python3 -c 'from datetime import datetime as dt;
    print(dt.now())'
```

I get this error::

```
$ python3 -c 'from datetime import datetime as dt;
/bin/bash: eval: line 69: syntax error near unexpected token `('
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 2
```

On this issue [Multiline YAML string for GitLab CI (.gitlab-ci.yml)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42560083/3313834) they talk about an `echo 'multiples lines string to echo'` and propose to keep it as a one liner or to pre-process the yml with `ruamel.yaml`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline YAML string for GitLab CI (.gitlab-ci.yml)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560083/multiline-yaml-string-for-gitlab-ci-gitlab-ci-yml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do it. The pipe is not supported by docker-ci.

```
image: python:latest

before_script:
  - >
    python3 -c 'from datetime import datetime as dt;
    print(dt.now())'
```