# post curl data from yaml file on gitlab

Tags: curl, yaml, gitlab

```
- >-
    curl
    -X POST
    --data-urlencode
    "payload={\"channel\": \"#space-unit-tests\", \"username\": \"webhookbot\", \"text\": \"Total number of test cases = $((COUNT_TESTS+MAIN_COUNT)).\", \"icon_emoji\": \":ghost:\"}"
    https://hooks.slack.com/services/...
```

I am trying to post some data to slack using slack api from gitlab ci file using curl but the above code gives me following error:

```
$ curl # collapsed multi-line command
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

is there any problem with my multiline curl command ? I seached here and google but can not find any problem with curl multiline command.

Comment: This might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560083/multiline-yaml-string-for-gitlab-ci-gitlab-ci-yml

Answer (score 0):

Add curl command after a pipe symbol in the same format which I attached. It is working Yaml code.

```
Script:
  -|
   curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"text": "Sample Test"}' "https://outlook.office.com/webhook/..."
```